# How to setup CORS between two CloudFront Distributions?

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, amazon-cloudfront, api-gateway

I have two CloudFront Distributions:

- one uses S3 as Origin - route53 Domain - example.com
- second uses API Gateway URL as Origin. - route53 Domain - api.com

JS Code is hosted on S3 and First Cloudfront Distribution.
`https://example.com/test.html` is giving call to `https://api.com/api?<queryParameters>`

However I am getting error saying:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.com/api?<queryParameters>' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I tried adding `Access-Control-Request-Headers`,`Access-Control-Request-Method` and `Origin` in Whitelist of `Cache Based on Selected Request Headers` in API CloudFront Behavior. Still no luck

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it as 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: HTTP Status code is 200 for API URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got resolved by adding Header message in Lambda function response.
Similar to this:

```
   response["headers"] = {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' 
   }
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html